# Text inside multirow is not readable

Tags: tabularx, multirow

I have a text inside multirow that for some reason is not readable.

```
\begingroup
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{ >{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}%
        {| >{\hsize=1.0\hsize}K|
         >{\hsize=1.00\hsize}X|
         >{\hsize=1.00\hsize}X|
         >{\hsize=1.00\hsize}X|
         >{\hsize=1.00\hsize}X|
        }

\hline
\rowcolor{gray!50}\textbf{Code 1} & \textbf{Code 2} & \textbf{code3} &      \textbf{code 4} & \textbf{code5}\\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
\endhead 

\multirow{4}{*}{\parbox{1.5cm}{Long text to break aaaaaa}}   
& xyzxyzxyz
& xyzxyzxyz    
& xyzxyzxyz  
& xyzxyzxyz
\\
\cline{2-5}
& xyzxyzxyz
& xyzxyzxyz
& xyzxyzxyz  
& xyzxyzxyz 
\\
\cline{2-5}
 & xyzxyzxyz
 & xyzxyzxyz  
 & xyzxyzxyz  
 & xyzxyzxyz 
 \\
\cline{2-5}

 & xyzxyzxyz 
 & xyzxyzxyz 
 & xyzxyzxyz  
 & xyzxyzxyz  
\\
\hline 
\end{tabularx}

\endgroup
```

I should see the multirow with the text "Long text to break aaaaaa" but I see something like in this screen:

[image]

The definition of columntype K is:

```
  \newcolumntype{K}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash \columncolor{blue!10}}m{3cm}}
```

How can I make the text readable?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `>{\hsize=1.0\hsize}` directives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put the `\multirow` command in the 4th row, with a negative value for the number of rows. As @Mico pointed, `>{\hsize=1.0\hsize}` is useless, as it is the default for `X` columns. This specification is used if you want to have unequal width X columns.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ltablex, multirow, ragged2e}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} \newcolumntype{K}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash \columncolor{blue!10}}m{3cm}}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{ >{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\keepXColumns
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}%
{|K|*{4}{X|}}
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!50}\textbf{Code 1} & \textbf{Code 2} & \textbf{code3} & \textbf{code 4} & \textbf{code5}\\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
\endhead
& xyzxyzxyz
& xyzxyzxyz
& xyzxyzxyz
& xyzxyzxyz
\\
\cline{2-5}
& xyzxyzxyz
& xyzxyzxyz
& xyzxyzxyz
& xyzxyzxyz
\\
\cline{2-5}
& xyzxyzxyz
& xyzxyzxyz
& xyzxyzxyz
& xyzxyzxyz
\\
\cline{2-5}
\multirow{-4}{*}{\parbox{1.5cm}{Long text to break aaaaaa}}
& xyzxyzxyz
& xyzxyzxyz
& xyzxyzxyz
& xyzxyzxyz
\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from pp. 7f. of the user guide of the `multirow` package:

> If you use `\multirow` with the `colortbl` package you have to take precautions if you
>   want to color the column that has the `\multirow` in it. The `colortbl` package works
>   by coloring each cell separately. So if you use `\multirow` with a positive `<nrows>`
>   value, `colortbl` will first color the top cell, then `\multirow` will typeset `<nrows>`
>   cells starting with this cell, and later `colortbl` will color the other cells, effectively
>   hiding the text in that area. This can be solved by putting the `\multirow` in the
>   last row with a *negative* `<nrows>` value.

Applied to your code, this means that instead of placing

```
\multirow{4}{*}{\parbox{1.5cm}{Long text to break aaaaaa}}
```

in the first row, you should place

```
\multirow{-4}{*}{\parbox{1.5cm}{Long text to break aaaaaa}}
```

in the last row.

Answer (score 3):

Almost the same answer as of *Bernard* (he bit mi for five minutes which I spend for looking for K column type definition and guess, why you use elements of long table in one simple table).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{K}{>{\RaggedRight\cellcolor{blue!10}}m{3cm}}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{ >{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|K|X|X|X|X|}
    \hline
\rowcolor{gray!50}
\textbf{Code 1} & \textbf{Code 2} & \textbf{code3} & \textbf{code 4} & \textbf{code5}\\
    \hline
    & xyzxyzxyz
    & xyzxyzxyz
    & xyzxyzxyz
    & xyzxyzxyz     \\
\cline{2-5}
    & xyzxyzxyz
    & xyzxyzxyz
    & xyzxyzxyz
    & xyzxyzxyz     \\
\cline{2-5}
     & xyzxyzxyz
     & xyzxyzxyz
     & xyzxyzxyz
     & xyzxyzxyz    \\
\cline{2-5}
\multirow{-4}{=}{Long text to break aaaaaa}
    & xyzxyzxyz
    & xyzxyzxyz
    & xyzxyzxyz
    & xyzxyzxyz     \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]